# Return rows in "group" - specific to certain values - and only those values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table - with columns claimID and procedureCode - there can be multiple procedureCode values assigned to a claimID - I have one query where I say -

```
SELECT claimID FROM #table WHERE procedureCode IN ('1234','6789')
```

Which obviously beings me back all claimIDs with those procedureCodes - the claimIDs returned may also contain other procedureCodes as well - so what I need to do is to say only bring me back the claimIDs where only the procedureCodes '1234' and '6789' exist - with no other procedureCodes associated with the claimIDs.

OK - ON the below - I need a list of claimIDs WHERE procedureCode IN ('1234','5678') - and ONLY those codes - so claimID 1 would qualify but not claimID 2 as claimID 2 has another procedureCode that is not in ('1234','5678')

```
CREATE TABLE #claims (claimID int, procedureCode varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #claims 
SELECT 1, '1234'
UNION
SELECT 1, '5678'
UNION
SELECT 2, '4455'
UNION
SELECT 2, '1234'
UNION
SELECT 3, '8899'
UNION
SELECT 3, '6677'

SELECT * FROM #claims
```

And here is my "real" query - I am trying to say - via the below - bring back all rows where proceduresCodes are in ('99281', '99282', '99283', '99284', '99285') - but now need to say - bring back only claimNo(s) where the ClaimNo has ('99281', '99282', '99283', '99284', '99285') associated with it and ONLY those codes - no others - make sense?

```
SELECT DISTINCT procedureCode,
COUNT(claimNo),
SUM(CAST(a.amount as money))/COUNT(claimNo) AS [837_Claim_Amt] ,
SUM(CAST(b.ClaimAmount as money))/COUNT(claimNo) AS [835_Claim_Amt],
SUM(CAST(b.ClaimPaid as money))/COUNT(claimNo) AS [835_Claim_Paid_Amt]
FROM ##Claims837 a
JOIN ##835Claims b ON a.claimNo = b.ClaimID
JOIN edi_paidclaimlines p ON b.ID = p.claimID
WHERE p.procedureCode IN ('99281', '99282', '99283', '99284', '99285')
GROUP BY procedureCode
ORDER BY procedureCode
```

Comment: Could you show some sample data and desired output?  I'm a bit confused as to what you are trying to describe.

Comment: OK - ON the below - I need a list of claimIDs WHERE procedureCode IN ('1234','5678') - and ONLY those codes - so claimID 1 would qualify but not claimID 2 as claimID 2 has another procedureCode that is not in ('1234','5678')

    CREATE TABLE #claims (claimID int, procedureCode varchar(10))
    INSERT INTO #claims 
    SELECT 1, '1234'
    UNION
    SELECT 1, '5678'
    UNION
    SELECT 2, '4455'
    UNION
    SELECT 2, '1234'
    UNION
    SELECT 3, '8899'
    UNION
    SELECT 3, '6677'

    SELECT * FROM #claims

Comment: I think the OP miss typed `'6789'` and it should be `'5678'`. All answers below should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only few values this is the most efficient and also the most readable way:

```
SELECT t1.claimID FROM #claims t1 
WHERE  t1.procedureCode IN ('1234','6789')
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM #claims t2
    WHERE t2.ClaimID = t1.ClaimID
      AND t2.procedureCode NOT IN ('1234','6789')
)
```

Here is your sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20800/0

The query yields no records, because all matching `claimID` have another `procedureCode` which is not in ('1234','6789').

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
into   #onlyIncluded
from   #table
where  ProcedureCode in ('1234','6789')

select distinct claimid
into   #thoseToExclude
from   #table
where  ProcedureCode not in ('1234','6789')

select  distinct claimid
into    #Final
from    #onlyIncluded
where   claimid not in (select claimid from #thoseToExclude)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little simpler...

```
select ClaimID
from #claims
group by ClaimID
-- the count of claims in your list match the total count of claims
having count(*) = sum(case when procedureCode IN ('1234','6789') then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ClaimId FROM #table
    WHERE ProcedureCode IN ('1234','6789')
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ClaimId FROM #table
    WHERE ProcedureCode NOT IN ('1234','6789')
```